# Bind click even on image tag

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm new in Ionic with Angular and I have a dynamic object that I want to access value on HTML `img click`

TS:

```
showOptions = false; 
options = [
    {
      id: '0',
      icon: 'assets/icons/set-comparison.svg',
      text: 'Set Comparison',
      action: 'setComparison()'
    },
   ....
  ];
 selectedOptionItem = this.options[0];
```

HTML:

```
<li *ngFor="let item of options" class="sidebar__content"   [ngClass]="{ 'active' : item === selectedMenuItem }">
          <button class="btn" (click)="selectedOptionItem = item">
            <img 
              [attr.src]="_measures.selectedMeasure.id === 'i' ? item.icon : item.icon2" 
              class="sidebar__content custom__icon" 
              (click) ="item.action">
          </button>
        </li>
```

I tried as `(click) ="item.action"` but it does not make an action

I created a normal button to see if the event works correctly as:

```
<button class="nav-link btn-sm btn btn-outline" (click)="setComparison()">
          Set comparison <i class="mdi mdi-compare-horizontal"></i>
        </button>
```

And yes, it works correctly, how can I access the property of my object correctly? Regards

SetComparison component:

```
async setComparison() {
    const modal = await this.modalCtrl.create({
      component: SetComparisonComponent,
      cssClass: 'modal-comparison',
      animated: true
    });
    modal.onDidDismiss().then((data) => {
      if (data) {
      }
    });
    return await modal.present();
  }
```

Modal Ctrl:

```
constructor(
    private modalCtrl: ModalController
   ....
     )
```

ModalController:

```
export declare class ModalController extends OverlayBaseController<ModalOptions, HTMLIonModalElement> {
    private angularDelegate;
    private resolver;
    private injector;
    constructor(angularDelegate: AngularDelegate, resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver, injector: Injector);
    create(opts: ModalOptions): Promise<HTMLIonModalElement>;
    static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<ModalController, never>;
    static ɵprov: ɵngcc0.ɵɵInjectableDef<ModalController>;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, the `action` property in the item in the `options` array does not store a reference to a function, but a string of the function name, because it's put between quotes. In addition, if you were to remove the single quotes, you would also run into problems, because the function reference includes parentheses behind it, meaning that it will get called as soon as the TypeScript file is included. Finally, I'm guessing that unless the function is globally defined, calling it as simply `setComparison` won't suffice either, because this does not specify the context of the function. If the `setComparison` function is defined in the same scope that the rest of your TypeScript code is, referring to it with the `this` keyword should be enough.

To solve your problem, you need to make two adjustments:

- Within the action parameter, store a reference to the function that is not actively being called, as such:
  `action: this.setComparison`
- Within the click handler, actively call the reference to the function that is stored in the `action` property, as such: `(click)="item.action()"`

Comment: Did you change the `action` parameter to a valid function reference as well? If the `action` parameter is still a string, calling it as a function (by adding parentheses) will not work.

Comment: Yes, now I get this error: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'create')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'create')

Comment: I updated my question with the setComparison method

Comment: Could you show how you are initializing the modalCtrl as well?

Comment: Yes, I already added it

Comment: I'm not sure if this is an issue related to your original question. The error message you posted suggests that you're reaching the `setComparison` function, but that there is something wrong with how the modalCtrl is initialised (perhaps it is not initialised in the same class as where the `setComparison` function is?), because it is viewed as undefined. However, it does suggest that you reach the function once you click the button.

Comment: That is weird, because if use action: `this.setComparison()` it executes the function correctly once I start the view, but it does not work if trying to execute with click event

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you any further there - If you set your action parameter to this.setComparison (without parentheses) and called the click event as item.action(), that should give the same result as using setComparison() in the click event directly.